# Geo-processing Package for ArcGIS Runtime 10.2

Tags: modelbuilder, arcgis-10.4, arcgis-runtime, geoprocessing-package

I am using ArcGIS 10.4.1 And Java SDK for ArcGIS Runtime 10.2. I created a geo-processing package in ArcMap that is exactly same with the the "SimpleBuffer.gpk" available with the sample dataset. I am using **scratchworkspace** and set its location according to my output. The sample dataset gpk is running fine and creating tasks in arcgis runtime created server. But when i provide my custom gpk in ArcGIS Runtime it does not generate any tasks.What possible reasons can be for arcgis runtime not creating tasks.  Is there any online tutorial available that would help me in knowning more about creating geo-processing packages.  All of my data is in the same folder to that of gpk. My model builder diagram is exactly same to that of sample buffer dataset.

Comment: Can you consume the GPK back into ArcMap? If so, its probably a good GPK. Can you get to the Services Directory of the GPK after starting up LocalServer? (Some good tips here: http://www.andyfrench.info/2013/11/arcgis-runtime-sdk-for-wpf-tips-and.html)

Comment: Yes, I can consume it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately 10.4.1 created GPK's will not work with ArcGIS Runtime for Java SDK 10.2.x.  You need to use GPK's from 10.3 with version 10.2.x of ArcGIS Java Runtime.  Support for GPK's from 10.2.4 and above will be in the local server of [ArcGIS Runtime Java Quartz](https://developers.arcgis.com/java/beta/) when released.

Comment: Yes, I used GPK from 10.2.2 version of ArcGIS and it solved the problem. Thank you for your time.